# How can I set environment variables in a Heroku app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, dotenv

So I'm currently working on a side project that requires a database. I choose to opt for MongoDB. I have the dotenv package installed so I can use this to save my secret mongoDB connection string.

I'd like to deploy my application to Heroku, but of course I don't want to push my .env to a github repo for this. Is there any way around this? It is a heroku-git repo but I have no idea how secure this would be. Anyone any other ideas on how to still keep the connection string secret and push the app to a platform like Heroku?

Comment: Check the settings tab > reveal config vars. Add your env variables there and they should be available when you are deploying your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Settings** tab of your app, the option is present

Comment: And how would I integrate these variables inside the code itself? For a .env file you can use process.env.<KEY>, is this the same for Heroku?

Comment: You need `require('dotenv').config()` in your main server file, after that you should have them available https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: So if I add the environment variables currently in my .env to the Heroku settings as the same key/values it should work?